# Recover Time Machine without the password

Tags: macos, time-machine, password, encryption

I'm having a issue with a Time Machine backup made on an external USB drive.
The TM backup is encrypted and I can't remember the password …
Does anybody know a tool to brute force the password ? (I remember the password is about 10 characters and alphanumeric (except for a "!" somewhere).

I'm running Mavericks.

Comment: What would be the purpose of strong password if it can be cracked. Giving that kind information here would be wrong.

Comment: Anybody willing to do some calculations here on how long it would take to brute force a 10 digit alphanumeric password, including the time it takes to try each combination against the drive?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [libfvde](https://code.google.com/p/libfvde/). It doesn't explicitly say it supports Mavericks, but might be worth a try.

Comment: Please include some details, a one-liner does not have much details and the URL might die.

Comment: I tried to clone the source repo, but it's empty :-/ Edit: I didn't see the download link when I checked, I'll try this one tonight.

Answer (score -1):

Trust Me, there is no tool to decrypt the encrypted hard disk. there is no way to recover this

Comment: i answered because i am sure this will doesn't work, i experienced this year ago and i lost my data, in order not to waste his time, efforts and money, That's my point thank you for clarification.